# Creating new column in data frame in R by comparing 2 existing columns and then deleting the latter

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have yet another question which I have been trying to solve for the past few hours unsuccessfully. It involves some dataset manipulation in R. Imagine that I have the following sample dataset:

```
a,b,v,r
1,3,1,0
2,5,1,1
3,6,0,1
1,5,1,0
2,4,1,1
3,6,0,1
```

I need to create a third column (say m) by comparing the values of the columns [v,r] by the following rules. If v = 1, r = 0 then m = 0. If v = 1, r = 1, then m = 1 and if v = 0, r = 1, then m = 2. [v,r] can never take the values (0,0).

I am wondering how I can create the third column and also delete the columns v,r in one line. Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data.table` (1.8.8):

```
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, `:=`(m = (!v) * 1 + r, v = NULL, r=NULL)]
#    a b m
# 1: 1 3 0
# 2: 2 5 1
# 3: 3 6 2
# 4: 1 5 0
# 5: 2 4 1
# 6: 3 6 2
```

Comment: Very nice with the `(!v) * 1 + r`!

Comment: +1 for figuring out v, r and m relationship.. I was thinking on lines of binary numbers :p

Comment: Your solutions is giving me the following error: Error: unexpected '=' in "gbbc1[ , `:=`(gbbc1$exp =" where gbbc1 is the name of the dataset and exp is the required column which doesn't yet exist.

Comment: why are you using `gbbc1$exp` instead of just `exp`?? If you see my post, I don't use `dt$` inside `dt[.]`.

Comment: Actually, this just solved my problem ! I completely overlooked that. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

It's not one line (so not nearly as snappy as @Arun's `data.table` solution) but here is one approach with `within` and `ifelse`:

```
within(mydf, {
  m <- ifelse(v == 1 & r == 0, 0, ifelse(v == 1 & r == 1, 1, 2))
  rm(v, r)
})
#   a b m
# 1 1 3 0
# 2 2 5 1
# 3 3 6 2
# 4 1 5 0
# 5 2 4 1
# 6 3 6 2
```

Comment: +1, this can still be done in 1 line by using `;` between two statements ;)

Comment: This answer is also good but I selected the above because on my large dataset it is much faster and doesn't print out the rows. Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2):

using `transform` from `base` packages

```
DF <- read.csv(textConnection("a,b,v,r\n1,3,1,0\n2,5,1,1\n3,6,0,1\n1,5,1,0\n2,4,1,1\n3,6,0,1"), header = TRUE)

transform(DF, m = (!v) * 1 + r, v = NULL, r = NULL)
##   a b m
## 1 1 3 0
## 2 2 5 1
## 3 3 6 2
## 4 1 5 0
## 5 2 4 1
## 6 3 6 2
```